# Is It Possible To Truncate (or limit the amount of words displayed) On A Rendered Post in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble with my bloglike application I'm building.

Essentially I have posts which are displayed using a _post partial. I use this two different ways: as part of a feed (displaying all posts) and when the specific post is clicked on.

When the post is part of the overall feed I want to limit the amount of characters that are displayed to keep things tidy. This is how posts are displayed in the feed:

```
<% @posts_by_month.each do |monthname, posts| %>

<div style="clear:left"><h2><%= monthname %></h2></div>

   <% for post in posts %>

     <div style="float:left;width:33%">  

    <ol class="posts">

      <% if post.status == 'new' %>
      <div class="new-post">
       <%= link_to edit_post_path(post) do %>
       <%= render post.first(80) %>
       <% end %>
     </div>

     <% else %>
     <div class="edited-post">
      <%= link_to post_path(post) do %>
      <%= render post %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <% end %>

  </ol>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

When I change the line <%= render post %> to <%= render post.first(80) %> to limit it to the first 80 characters I get the error: "undefined method `first' for #< Post:0xc5785e0 >". The same happens with truncate.

I can't put the truncate in the _post partial because then it will truncate it when the specific post is clicked on, which is not what I want. How do I make it so for this feed of posts the posts are limited to a certain number of characters?

**Edited to add**
My post partial:

```
<div id="post-<%= post.id %>">
  <span class="timestamp">
    <%= post.created_at.strftime('%A, %b %d')%>
      <span class="content"><%= post.content %></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share your post partial

Comment: What is `render` doing inside the `link_to`?

Comment: try this https://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate

Comment: The link to links to the post so you can see it in more detail. The render shows all of the post currently, however I want it to just display a truncated amount of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't put the truncate in the _post partial because then it will truncate it when the specific post is clicked on, which is not what I want.

Naturally. This then calls for one of two solutions.

1. Truncate text of post objects prior to rendering, or otherwise make the post partial see shortened text (for example, use a Presenter pattern)

   ```
   <% for post in posts %>
     <% post.title = truncate(post.title) %> // truncate
     <%= render post %> // then render
   ```
2. Use another partial for rendering posts on the index page, the one with `truncate` inside.

Comment: Can you expand on the first solution a little more? I don't quite understand how to integrate it into my current code, but it sounds like the best approach

Comment: @Andrew: what specifically don't you understand about that?

Comment: I currently render the whole post and I'm not sure how to just render a "post.title" (I haven't given a title field to my posts or anything). I tried copy/pasting your code as written into mine and it did not work.

Comment: @Andrew: that line is not rendering title. It's truncating it. Then you render the whole post, as you do. If you don't have title, then truncate whatever it is you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%= render partial: 'post', :locals => {:post => post, :length => 80} %>
```

and in your partial,

```
<div id="post-<%= post.id %>">
  <span class="timestamp">
    <%= post.created_at.strftime('%A, %b %d')%>
      <span class="content"><%= length.present? ? post.content.first(length) : post.content %></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I get the error "Missing partial users/_post, application/_post with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}" - my post partial is in my views, in a folder called Posts

Comment: then change it to 'Posts/post'